# How to run tap operator when any given observables emits value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
const annotationEvent = event1$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === DemoEvent.select || type === DemoEvent.unselect),
      delay(100),
      throttleTime(50),
      tap(_ => doSomething())
    );
    const imageApplicationEvent = event2$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === TestEvent.selectItem || type === TestEvent.unselectItem),
      delay(100),
      throttleTime(50),
      tap(_ => doSomething())
    );
forkJoin([annotationEvent, imageApplicationEvent]).subscribe();
```

Above code, `event1$` and `event2` is a long live Observable that is returned by `behaviorSubject.asObservable`. As you can see, after filtering the type of emitted value, there are duplicated code written. Im trying to run `doSomething` method when any given Observables(in this scenario it would be `event1$` and `event2$`) emits value. I assumed that piping the forkJoin operator `tap` operator would do the same thing with more simpler code. like this

```
const annotationEvent = event1$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === DemoEvent.select || type === DemoEvent.unselect)
    );
    const imageApplicationEvent = event2$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === TestEvent.selectItem || type === TestEvent.unselectItem)
    );
forkJoin([annotationEvent, imageApplicationEvent]).pipe(
      delay(100),
      throttleTime(50),
      tap(_ => doSomething())).subscribe();
```

But it seems it's not working as I expected and I assume that forkJoin emit the last emitted value only when all given observable completes, and since `event1$` and `event2$` does not completes it did not run as I expected. I tried `zip` and `combineLatest` or etc operators that groups observable but non of them achieves what I want to do.

conclusion, are there any possible ways to run a code when any given of observables emits value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the 'merge' operator,
e.g.

```
const annotationEvent = event1$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === DemoEvent.select || type === DemoEvent.unselect)
    );

const imageApplicationEvent = event2$.pipe(
      filter(({ type }) => type === TestEvent.selectItem || type === TestEvent.unselectItem)
    );

merge(annotationEvent, imageApplicationEvent).pipe(
      delay(100),
      throttleTime(50),
      tap(_ => doSomething())).subscribe();
```

Comment: Tried using 'merge' operator. but  'doSomething' run when only subscribed, not when event1$ or event2$ emits value :(

Comment: oops! I passed the argument wrong!(grouped arguments with an array). by spreading the arguments its working as i expected thank you very much :)